# rq-dashboard on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, redis, rq

I'm trying to get rq-dashboard to work on my Redis server created through Heroku. I added it to my Flask app using

```
from flask import Flask
import rq_dashboard

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(rq_dashboard.default_settings)
app.register_blueprint(rq_dashboard.blueprint, url_prefix="/rq")
```

But upon accessing the `/rq` URL I'm getting

```
Error 1 connecting to ec2-52-206-160-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19229. [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091).
```

Any recommendations on what to do?

Comment: https://github.com/Parallels/rq-dashboard/issues/395

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `?ssl_cert_reqs=none` at the end of your connection string, and it will bypass SSL cert verification.

For example, get your redis connection string by doing a:

`heroku config -a your_app_name|grep redis`

You get something like:
`REDIS_URL rediss://:xxxxx@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-n.amazonaws.com:yyyy`

You can use that connection string with rq-dashboard, now add `?ssl_cert_reqs=none` to the end, and it'll work.

`rq-dashboard -u rediss://.....:yyyy?ssl_cert_reqs=none`